# Can I synch OverLeaf with an Enterprise GitHub account (not a regular account)?

Tags: github, overleaf

I am a university student, and I am provided an enterprise GitHub account from my school. Our research group members use the university-provided enterprise GitHub accounts to maintain the research-related repos.

I would like to sync my OverLeaf project with my university enterprise GitHub account. I was able to successfully sync my OverLeaf project with my personal GitHub account, which uses my Gmail. However, I was not able to accomplish the former. When I encounter the menu dialog box in OverLeaf to sync OverLeaf to GitHub, it does not seem to recognize my enterprise GitHub account.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Ahmad